# How to convert this ScrollView into ListView without any error

Tags: android

It currently displays list of files from sdcard, however I want to add  some additional features.

But I'm unable to add those in scroll view and also the styling is limited in ScrollView hence want it to change to ListView.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Search deference  about Listview and ScrollView

Comment: Will do it @milapTank Thanks for stopping by